# How to open/close all collapsed/open cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Is there a way to open/close all collapsed/open cells? The reason is for a long notebook, it is convenient to see all the section and subsection headings at once.

Comment: STEP 1: Select All  (Edit Menu -> Select All). ............STEP 2: Cell Menu -> Grouping -> Close All Subgroups

Comment: Ctrl+A,Ctrl+Shift+]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Per Hector's comment)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all cells and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to close them. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> opens closed cells.