# How to tell Mathematica to collapse all of its sections/subsections in one command?

Tags: syntax, formatting, styling

Is there any command allowing one to collapse all the heading sections in Mathematica (each title content, each chapter, and so on)?

I am interested not in [the buttons combination](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29960/how-to-open-close-all-collapsed-open-cells), but rather in the plain command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectAll"]
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
```